# Pinterest - how to display latest pin (image and title)?

Tags: api, pinterest

I'd like to display the image and title of the latest pin from a board on Pinterest, in a similar format to the Pin Widget, but it has to dynamically display the latest added pin and not be hard coded.

Do I need to use PHP, or can this be done with js?

I'd prefer js but I can't see how to either, limit the images/pins returned by the Profile and Board widgets, or dynamically load an image for the Pin It widget.

I've also tried the RSS feed (using the code below), but this seems to display random pins (I can delete a pin and it will still display) when set to display 1:

```
google.load('feeds', '1');

function initialize() {
var feed = new google.feeds.Feed('https://www.pinterest.com/[username]/[board]/feed.rss'); // update username

feed.setNumEntries(1); // set number of results to show

feed.load(function(result) {
        if (!result.error) {
            var container = document.getElementById('pinfeed'); // look for our display container

            for (var i = 0; i < result.feed.entries.length; i++) { // loop through results

                var entry   = result.feed.entries[i],
                content = entry.content, // get "content" which includes img element
                regex   = /src="(.*?)"/, // look for img element in content
                src     = regex.exec(content)[1]; // pull the src out, 

                // put our link to the pin with img into our container:
                container.innerHTML = '<a href="'+ entry.link + '" target="_blank"><img src="'+ src + '" /></a>';
            }
        }
});
}
google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
```

Comment: This could be done with both `PHP` and `Javascript` they can interact with the Pintrest API independently. Have you tried anything yet ?

Comment: I've created widgets, but the board, and profile, widgets display all the board pins, and the pin widget requires a hard coded pin id, I can't see how to limit these, or provide a dynamic pin id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do this. The right way and the hack way.

The right way is to use the new public [Pinterest API](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/getting-started/introduction/). You have a user login and then fetch their pins. You can change the fields to include all the pieces you want back. The link to get PDK is [here](http://assets.pinterest.com/sdk/sdk.js).

```
PDK.login({scope:'read_public'}, function() {
    if (session) {
        PDK.me('pins', {fields: 'created_at,image,note'}, function(pins) {
            ...do something with the pins
        });
    }
});
```

The hack way to do it is to use the undocumented API used for the Pinterest widgets. It is not guaranteed to be in order of date, though it usually is, and can change or cease to exist at any point in time in the future. You can ping a url like this, by replacing username and the jsonp callback.

`https://api.pinterest.com/v3/pidgets/users/<username>/pins/?callback=<callback>`

Comment: I just want to display the latest pin, do I have to create an app and log in to do even this?

Comment: The other option is to use the undocumented API and grab the first Pin in the list.

Comment: When using the new API, does the user have to explicitly login? It doesn't look like it works in a similar way to instagram where you authorise through the app?

Comment: You have to be logged into Instagram to authorize as well. I'm confused by the question. Once you have logged in once, however, you can save the access token and they won't have to be logged in after that.

Comment: sorry, I've tried the js sdk but the only thing i could get it to do was present a login form, I want to display a pin on a web page, but I don't want to have to log in to do that, can I authorise without having to login through a login form?

Comment: If you use the undocumented API you don't have to be logged in. I'm lobbying to open some of the documented endpoints without authentication, and will hopefully have that done soon.

Comment: sorry, to be clear, you have to login via a form to get responses from the API?

Comment: Nope, you don't need anything for the undocumented API. Just create a script tag, set the src to the url, and make sure you have the callback variable specified on the global window.

Comment: sorry, I didn't explain clearly, again! I meant do you have to login via a form to use the new public Pinterest API, even for the get pin method?

Comment: For now. :( Hopefully that will change soon!

Comment: Thanks Zack, you've been incredibly helpful.

Comment: Is it possible to display the latest pin from a pinterest feed on my website, using the API, without having to log in, yet?