# How to get a user's latest board pins with the Pinterest API?

Tags: pinterest

I have a website on which I want to display 4 pins from the latest board of a given pinterest user (always the same user actually).

Planning to use the Pinterest API. I read all the Pinterest API docs and searched on the web as well, and it seems the website visitor will need to authorize or login on Pinterest in some way, which I don't want really (according to this [Pinterest - how to display latest pin (image and title)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33012430/pinterest-how-to-display-latest-pin-image-and-title)). I just want the user to see the images...

Any solution for this? Basically, I just want to fetch the board by its date and username and fetch some pins from that board.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using NodeJS, and knowing the board name, you can do :

va  PDK             = require('node-pinterest')
   ,pinterest       = PDK.init(your_pinterest_token)
pinterest.api('boards/' + board + '/pins',{ qs: {fields: 'id,created_at,note }}).then(function(result) {
// console.log(result)
})

Comment: Yea I ended up with a similar solution, having to know the board name before hand... no way to get the latest board with neither v1, v2 or v3 API.

Answer (score 0):

very easy just use this code

```
 getPinterestData(boardName) {
 let access_token =  'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-zSul0atEQt2fi6A-iwAAAAA';
 return this.http.get('https://api.pinterest.com/v1/boards/myboardNamme/'+ boardName +'/pins/?access_token='+ access_token +'&fields=id%2Cnote%2Cimage')
   .map((res: Response) =>
     res.json())
   .catch((error: any) =>
     Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
```

}